Drop Down On Image Click In MudBlazor
I am creating a user login page  after success login the user image is displaying in the appbar.
I want to implement functionality in such a way that when i click on image logout option should appear in the drop down along with FAQ menu.
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using ProfitBookingApp.Client.Components

<MyMudThemeProvider />
<MyMudProviders />

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Class="ml-3">Portfolio</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudAvatar>
            <MudImage Src="images/mony.jpg" ></MudImage>
        </MudAvatar>
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large" Class="my-16 pt-16">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

Please let me know if this is possible in Mudblazor
Thanks

There are various examples in the MudBlazor documentation for Custom Activators for MudMenu
MudMenu Custom Activator
In case for your MudAvatar you would implement it as:
<MudMenu>
    <ActivatorContent>
        <MudAvatar Image="images/mony.jpg" />
    </ActivatorContent>
    <ChildContent>
        <MudMenuItem>Profile</MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenuItem>Theme</MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenuItem>Usage</MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenuItem>Sign Out</MudMenuItem>
    </ChildContent>
</MudMenu>

MudBlazor snippet
